# Silverlight 4 Binding to ConverterParameter

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, binding, converters

I have a ValueConverter which needs to be called with a dynamic parameter, depending on a property. I can't see a way to do this ...

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidthValue, Source={StaticResource VisibleSize}, Converter={StaticResource Fraction}}"
```

The "Fraction" converter get's (or should get) a parameter of type System.Size, which contains a numerator and denumerator. This value (should) depend on a ItemCollection.Count. Resetting the ItemCollection should reinvoke the Converter with the new values.

My first idea was to manually change the ConverterParameter in CodeBehind on the PropertyChanged event of my ItemCollection DependencyProperty. But, as I know now, Silverlight has no GetBinding() method.
I heard about GetBindingExpression and tried to do. But MyGrid.GetBindingExpression(Grid.ActualHeightProperty) is always returning null, although the Binding is already established.

So, what can I do to reach my target?

---

My implementation was not much different. I set the ConverterParameter in CodeBehind just before the Converter is called via Binding. That hasn't worked (Parameter contains still the initialization value).

I'll try to use your suggestion. But why ConverterParameter can't be a DependencyPropery. What's the idea behind this? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If..
 what you mean by "depending on a property" is that there is another property of the DataContext apart from `ActualWidthValue` which you need in order to calculate the value you want to assign to Width
..then:

Modify the IValueConverter you call "Fraction" to take the entire object instead.  It can the acquire the value of `ActualWidthValue` and any other values it needs and then return the required width.

**Edit**

From your comment I see the my first "if.." paragraph is false.  You actually have a common value across the UserControl that this converter should be using.  In this case add a property to the converter, it is after all just another class.  When the property on the UserControl is set you assign its value to this property.   For example:-

Some Value converter:-

```
 public class SomeConverter : IValueConverter
 {

     public int SomeFactor { get; set }
     // IValueConverter implementation here uses SomeFactor
 }
```

UserControl xaml:-

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:SomeConverter x:Key="Fraction" SomeFactor="15" />
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

UserControl CodeBehind:-

```
 public int SomeFactor
 {
      get { return ((SomeConverter)Resources["Fraction"]).SomeFactor; }
      set { ((SomeConverter)Resources["Fraction").SomeFactor = value; }
 }
```

Comment: Right, I need another value - besides ActualWidthValue - to calculate the right output value. I wanted to pass this value as a parameter of my Convert() method. The coefficient - so to speak - is a property of my UserControl. The ActualWidthValue is a property of a StaticResource I use. So, how can I modify my IValueConverter to take the entire UserControl AND my ActualWidthValue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to be using a MultiBinding. It's a WPF feature, but as with a lot of things there's 3rd party implementations:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/

You could then pass in the ActualWidthValue and the item collection count in as separate parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know MultiBinding and already have an working implementation. But that doesn't matter here. I need only one value as a parameter. My problem is, that I'm not able to use the ConverterParameter with a Binding. Any StaticResource wokrs fine. Is there no possibility to establish a Binding with ConverterParameter?

Comment: If I do use a binding: Width="{Binding ActualWidthValue, Source={StaticResource VisibleSize}, Converter={StaticResource Fraction}, ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=ColumnFraction}}" then I get the message "Value does not fall within the expected range" ... Totally vacuous - in my opinion.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: you can't use a binding for a ConverterParameter.  The target of a binding (i.e. the property whose value is set to `{Binding ...}`) must be a dependency property, but Binding.ConverterParameter isn't a dependency property.  And as for the unhelpful error message, ... well, let's just say that's one aspect of Silverlight that could do with some improvement....

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps You Could Do:

```
<Image.Width>
<Binding Path="Rank" Converter="{StaticResource RankWidthConverter}" ConverterParameter="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=barBorder}" />
</Image.Width>
```