# Silverlight Binding converter

Tags: silverlight, binding, parameters, converters

I'm trying to bind a field to my coverter... But it seems like it's not possible...

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
  Source="{Binding LeaveApproved,Converter={StaticResource CommentTypeIconConverter},ConverterParameter={Binding TypeOfWorkId}}"
```

I want a different icon for when the TypeOfWorkId is 5 and the LeaveApproved is null. All the other Types of work should have an empty field, so no icon there. That's why I need the typeOfWorkId in my coverter.

Has anybody have any idea how to do this?

Grtz

Comment: [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509342/silverlight-4-binding-to-converterparameter) possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding is not possible in ConvertParameter (though you can use StaticResource).
To solve your case you will have to create another Property say LeaveApprovedTypeOfWorkId which will take into account you logic.

```
public YourType LeaveApprovedTypeOfWorkId {
  get{
    if(TypeOfWorkId==5 && LeaveApproved == null){
      return //something
    }
    else{
      return //something
    }
  }
}
```

Bind to this property instead.
Do not forget to **NotifyPoppertyChange** in case of **LeaveApproved** or **TypeOfWorkId** is **set**

Answer (score 1):

Dont set the property of the object and You will have your object in your convert. Just like that:

```
Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource xxxxxxConverterName }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CommentTypeIconConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int typeOfWorkId;
        if (value == null && parameter != null && int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out typeOfWorkId) && typeOfWorkId == 5)
            return new BitmapImage(...);
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Does this work for you?

It is better practice to use multibinding though for what you want to do..

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/06/silverlight-multibindings-how-to-attached-mutiple-bindings-to-a-single-property/

Comment: I'll have to multibind I guess... Never done it before. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: If you have devexpress then you can use their multibinding classes, if not then you can give this one another look to: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/  Btw it is possible to do what you want to do without multibinding...

Comment: I would prefer not to use multibinding... Is there a way to send my object to the converter?

Comment: Make a class that holds the two objects you are interested in and bind to an instance of that class.  eg: class x with properties LeaveAproved and TypeOfWorkId and then in your viewmodel you expose a property of class x