# Why can't I use IMultiValueConverter on Rectangle.Width?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, converters, ivalueconverter

I need to draw rectangles in an ItemsControl to a width calculated from a value defined in the bound collection and the max value of the collection.  So I figured I need to use a MultiValueConverter to pass in the item's value and the max value of the collection.

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509342/silverlight-4-binding-to-converterparameter) of adding a property to the converter works great as is, but not when I separate the view from the VM.

It looks like I can't set the width property with a MultiBinding though - my converter is getting called and returning the correct values, but I see no rectangles:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountInvitations}" />
                    <Rectangle Height="20" Fill="Black">
                        <Rectangle.Width>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiValueConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="CountInvitations" />
                                <Binding ElementName="MainLayout" Path="DataContext.MaxCount" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Rectangle.Width>
                    </Rectangle>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here's the converter:

```
int CellWidth = 200;
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    int count = int.Parse(values[0].ToString());
    int maxCount = int.Parse(values[1].ToString());
    var width = CellWidth / maxCount * count;
    return width;
}
```

Is it just not possible to set Rectangle.Width via MultiBinding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  And that's why it didn't work.

The problem is that your bindings are evaluated after the Rectangle is rendered.  Once evaluated, the TextBlock removes any content elements.  I believe TextBlocks consider strings a "special case" and render those directly rather than creating child elements to house the text.  So, with the result of the binding being a string, the Rectangle gets removed from the visual tree.

Here's a short repro I threw together in a minute to illustrate.  First, the UI:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBlockContent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="525" Width="525">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <TextBlock Text="This text is static">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" 
                       Width="150"
                       Height="150" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThisTextIsSetByABinding}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" 
                       Width="150"
                       Height="150" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThisTextIsUpdatedByAButton}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" 
                       Width="150"
                       Height="150" />
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Click to update the last TextBlock"
                Command="{Binding}" />
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

This shows the three possible options--static text, a binding that's evaluated once, and a binding that is updated on a button press.

Here's the VM:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand
{
    // events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    // this property is set once prior to the binding being evaluated
    public string ThisTextIsSetByABinding { get; set; }
    private string _thisTextIsUpdatedByAButton = 
        "This text is updated by a button";
    // this one is updated and so is INPC
    public string ThisTextIsUpdatedByAButton
    {
        get
        {
            return _thisTextIsUpdatedByAButton;
        }
        set
        {
            _thisTextIsUpdatedByAButton = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new 
                PropertyChangedEventArgs("ThisTextIsUpdatedByAButton"));
        }
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ThisTextIsSetByABinding = "This text is set by a binding";
    }
    // ICommand impl
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ThisTextIsUpdatedByAButton = "Text updated!";
    }
}
```

(To save space, the VM acts as the ICommand)  We've got a text property that can be updated, and one that can't.  Now let's see how they render in the UI

[image: The UI as shown in the window]

Note, I didn't need to do the updatable property--both properties set by bindings don't have the rectangle.  Here, let's check the visual tree using Snoop to see if the rectangles are still there:

[image: What Snoop reports]

Notice that only the first TextBlock contains the Rectangle.  The next two have had the content removed by the action of the Binding.

So, yes, you can use a MultiBinding on a Rectangles' width, but you can't do it like this.  Besides, it's kind of a code smell to be throwing rectangles in your TextBlocks.

The solution is to combine your TextBlocks and your Rectangles using a parent container, not trying to use the TextBlock as a container itself.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the converter to return double gives me what I want:

[image]